# Is this an acceptable definition for REST API endpoints?

Tags: rest, api-design

I am looking for a REST API design that I can use to manage entities and relations.

An important point is that the REST API can also be used for imports. There is also the special feature that a foreign key can be specified for entities. If an entity with this foreign key already exists, it should be updated, otherwise it should be created.

I wanted to avoid additional URL's like `/bulk` or `/import` if possible. So I guess I bent the pure REST rules a bit.

Here is my definition so far. Is this still acceptable or do the experts here get a cold shiver?

#### Entities

| HTTP verbs | Plural URL | Singular URL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `GET` | `/entities` - retrieves collections of Entities resources. It is possible to use Request-Parameter or filters with a HTTP-Body like `{"filter":{...}}` | `/entities/{id}` retrieves single Entity resource |
| `POST` | `/entities` - creates or update a single Entity resource. | - |
| `PUT` | `/entities` - create or update collections of Entity resources. Use HTTP-Body `[{...}.{...}]` | `/entities/{id}` - update single Entity resource |
| `PATCH` | `/entities` - patch collection of Entity resources, see [JSON Patch](https://jsonpatch.com/) | `/entities/{id}` - patch single Entity resource, see [JSON Patch](https://jsonpatch.com/) |
| `DELETE` | `/entities` - delete Entity resources. It is possible to use Request-Parameter or filters with a HTTP-Body like `{"filter":{...}}`. Without filter all Entities will be deleted | `/entities/{id}` - delete single Entity resource |

#### Relations

| HTTP verbs | Plural URL | Singular URL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `GET` | `/entities/{id}/relations` - retrieves collections of Entities relations. It is possible to use Request-Parameter or filters with a HTTP-Body like `{"filter":{...}}` | `/entities/{id}/relations/{id}` retrieves single Entity relation |
| `POST` | `/entities/{id}/relations` - add a collection of Entity relations to the relations. Use HTTP-Body `[{relation_id},{relation_id}]` | - |
| `PUT` | `/entities/{id}/relations` - replace collection of Entity relations | - |
| `PATCH` | `/entities/{id}/relations` - patch collection of Entity relations, see [JSON Patch](https://jsonpatch.com/) | - |
| `DELETE` | `/entities/{id}/relations` - delete Entity relations. It is possible to use Request-Parameter or filters with a HTTP-Body like `{"filter":{...}}`. Without filter all Entity relations will be deleted | `/entities/{id}/relations/{relation_id}` - delete single Entity relations |

#### States

| HTTP verbs | Plural URL | Singular URL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `POST` | `/entities/activate` - activate Entity resources. It is possible to use Request-Parameter or filters with a HTTP-Body like `{"filter":{...}}` | `/entities/{id}/activate` - activate single Entity resource |
| `POST` | `/entities/deactivate` - deactivate Entity resources. It is possible to use Request-Parameter or filters with a HTTP-Body like `{"filter":{...}}` | `/entities/{id}/deactivate` - deactivate single Entity resource |

The status to be set can be named arbitrarily. For example also like `/entities/{id}/star` and `/entities/{id}/unstar`.  Enumerations are also possible. Like e.g. `/entities/{id}/speed/slow`, `/entities/{id}/speed/medium`, `/entities/{id}/speed/hight`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this still acceptable or do the experts here get a cold shiver?

Not acceptable - the description above suggests that you are trying to create specialized versions of HTTP methods to do what you want, rather than relying on the common standardized definitions that we all share.

My guess is that you haven't quite internalized the idea that your *resource* model and your *data* model are different things.

GET/PUT/POST/DELETE message semantics apply to the resource model.

> I wanted to avoid additional URL's like /bulk or /import if possible.

You can, technically, do that, but you may be making your life harder without realizing any real benefit.

It normally takes the form of [HTTP POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post) combined with distinct payloads for each of the different kinds of actions, and handler implementations that analyze the payload to understand the work to be done.

For example, on the HTML web, our only out-of-the-box option for [unsafe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-safe-methods) transfer of information to the server is a POST form, so if we want to achieve different effects on the same resource, we include in the body of the request metadata so that the server can understand our intent.

Comment: One reason for this was to avoid that each relation has to be set by a separate request.
If I understand this correctly, the right way would be to define own URL's for these cases which then use `POST`?